# How do you log proxy_pass in the nginx access log?

Tags: nginx

Given an nginx config:

```
proxy_pass http://yahoo.com;
```

How do you get the string "http://yahoo.com" in the access_log?  **$remote_addr** is the ip.

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/$proxy_host and $upstream_addr

Answer (score 32, accepted):

add this to your `log_format`

`$proxy_host` and `$upstream_addr`

^-courtesy of the commenter, Alex. Just adding here so that folks see it when visiting.

Answer (score 3):

You need `"$proxy_host" "$upstream_addr"` in your log_format.

```
    log_format  proxy_log  '[$time_local] $remote_addr - $remote_user "$host$request_uri" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"'
                      ' Proxy: "$proxy_host" "$upstream_addr"';
```

And then reference the log identifier in your appropriate access_log `access_log /dev/stdout proxy_log;`